# PHP ckeditor5 save to database issue

Tags: php, ckeditor

Saving to database is not working fine (bold is stored as stars, italic as underline, etc)

For example : **example** is saved as ** example **

```
    <?php
    include ("conn.php");
    $sql = "SELECT texte FROM TEST";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    ?>
    <body data-editor="ClassicEditor" data-collaboration="false">
    <form action='' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <textarea name="texte" class="editor">
            <?php echo $row["texte"];  ?>
        </textarea>
        <button type='submit' name="submit">ENVOYER</button>
    </form>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $data = $_POST["texte"];
        $sql = "UPDATE TEST SET texte='$data'";
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            echo $data." updated successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    }
    ?>
```